# Problem in understanding transistor

Tags: transistors, diodes, pn-junction

I am a high school student. We are taking transistor in our class but I couldn't understand the topic. I have read several answer on this site both for physics as well as electrical engineering stack exchange community.

What I didn't get is this :

I have read the definition of transistor  it says,

> It helps us to convert, low resistance signal to high resistance signal.

I am not able to understand what low and high resistance signals are. Or I do not understand what transistor is, how it works in various switches and circuits, and then I read about the types of transistor; PNP and NPN and how they are different. Can anyone help me in understanding this?

Comment: Can you use the schematic editor to provide us with an example that is troubling you? And your quote doesn't really make a lot of sense to me, either. At least, not in a general way. So I think you will need to unlearn some thoughts and replace them with others.

Comment: That's a really strange statement. Where did you find it?

Comment: I think you might be suffering from translation errors, either in the book you're reading, or you relating it to us. Once you understand a bipolar junction transistor (BJT), there is a viewpoint you could come from to see some truth in what you quoted. However, that's certainly not the way to start understanding what it does. For a BJT, you need to know that a small base current controls a large collector current. It's sensible to divide its operation into three modes, linear where VCE is >1v and Ice is finite, on where VCE is <1v, off where Ice is zero.

Comment: @jonk I will update my question sir!

Answer (score 0):

Well since no schemantic is provided i will assume you are talking about low power signal to high power signal. And you are talking about amplifier. Basically, you use transistor as a switch. low power signal controlls the switch which allows higher power signal to be conducted.

[image]

in case of the picture above transistor will not conduct any electricity.. If you close the switch the 50V load will be able to flow through transistor.

Here you can find a simulator that lets you study about different electric components.
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: Falstad is pretty basic - I wouldn't be inclined to recommend it to anyone.  Get full blown micro cap 12 while you can: https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: @Andyaka a lot of people would disagree with you. it is not very basic, it is very good for beginers to expiriment and build complex circuits.

Comment: Beginners may disagree of course.

Comment: @Andyaka it is targeted towards beginers, so people like poster can expirement with electonics in browser. ofc once you move on to mosfets and optos in falstad it becomes useless

Comment: @Anton stafeyev but you have mis understand my question, in first part of my question I have confusion in understanding what transistor is, and I relate my book detention to understand it.

Comment: Second part I have confusion how NPN transistor differ from PNP transistor.

Comment: @YuvrajSingh... i just provided you with an example of what transistor is and what it does. But it shouldnt be hard to google difference between pnp and npn transistor. as well as PN junctions and so on. without researching your self you wont get far.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev If someone asks you to explain what a bird is, and you show them a picture of an ostrich then you have not provided an explanation.